# Wordpress Crashes on Google Compute Engine

Tags: wordpress, google-compute-engine

we have several Wordpress Installations (Bitname and normal) on the Google Compute Engine and all of them are crashing several times a day. Mostly the database seems to be the problem.

Our Monitoring shows daily peaks on the CPU above 100% but there are only landingpages without any high performance apps on it. We have reinstalled wordpress and looked up any possible performance troublemaker like plugins. But nothing can be found. Wordpress and every plugin are updated to latest version.

[Monitoring Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1HTt.png)

Does anybody has a hint for us where to look for a solution?

Comment: Any logs to post? I'd be curious about whats happening on the server at the app level.

Comment: Also you might want to check out Trellis - which is a perfected WP instance you can just drop into the cloud: https://roots.io/trellis

Comment: Thx! I will try to get some logs.